# Using ddrescue to shred only rescued portions of disk

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue, shred

1. Magnetic drive has failed.
2. I used ddrescue to recover ~85% of it, with a map file, but the rest is borked and continuing to scrub it would take years.
3. I can return it for a replacement.
4. I'd like to shred my data first.
5. When I try to write to it, it works for the first few hundred MB but then starts pouring input/output errors and the drive becomes completely unavailable (/dev/sdd no longer exists).

So is it possible to use the map file from item 2 to write random data only to the portions of the drive that were recoverable and not attempt to write to the bad blocks?

Comment: Physical destruction is not an option?

Comment: @Panki not if it's going to be returned under warranty (item 3)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Fill-mode) gives you an example which is almost exactly what you want:

> When `ddrescue` is invoked with the option `--fill-mode` it operates in "fill mode", which is different from the default "rescue mode". That is, in "fill mode" `ddrescue` does not rescue anything. It only fills with data read from `infile` the blocks of `outfile` whose status character from `mapfile` coincides with one of the type characters specified in the argument to `--fill-mode`.
>
> […]
>
> In fill mode `mapfile` is updated to allow resumability when interrupted or in case of a crash, but as nothing is being rescued `mapfile` is not destroyed. The status line is the only part of `mapfile` that is modified.
>
> […]
>
> Example 2: Wipe only the good sectors, leaving the bad sectors alone. This way, the drive will still test bad (i.e., with unreadable sectors). This is the fastest way of wiping a failing drive, and is **especially useful when sending the drive back to the manufacturer for warranty replacement**.
>
> ```
> ddrescue --fill-mode=+ --force /dev/zero bad_drive mapfile
> ```

<sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

The only difference is you want to write random data, so `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/zero`.

Comment: Took 6 hours, but drive didn't disconnect!